# Removing elements with no children DOM PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'd like to remove all empty `<a>` tags from a string.

so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
```

and not:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Not empty</a>
```

However:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="puppy.jpg" alt="Not empty"></a>
```

is being removed as well.

Edit:
Basically images are being removed, because they seem to have an empty nodeValue. I want to keep the images. Why is nodeValue returning empty when there is an image between the `<a>` tags?

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
$content_before='
so:
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>

and not:
<a href="http://www.google.com">Not empty</a>

However:
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="puppy.jpg" alt="Not empty"></a>
';
$dom=new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content_before);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$anchors=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $a)
{
    $as[] = $a;
}
foreach($as as $a)
{
    $nodevalue=$a->nodeValue;
    $nodevalue=trim($nodevalue);

    if(empty($nodevalue)&&is_object($a))
    {
        #remove links without nodevalues
        $a->parentNode->removeChild($a);
    }
}
$content=$dom->saveHTML();
echo 'before:<br><textarea>'.$content_before.'</textarea>'; 
echo 'after<br><textarea>'.$content.'</textarea>';  

#what $content becomes:
$content='
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>so:


and not:
<a href="http://www.google.com">Not empty</a>

However:
</p></body></html>';

#What I want it to be:
$content_after='
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>so:

and not:
<a href="http://www.google.com">Not empty</a>

However:
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="puppy.jpg" alt="Not empty"></a>
</p></body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: What should be your final/desired output? can you add more information in your question.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use `xpath` querying, then get all elements which has no/empty children. After that, remove all those elements with regression:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content_before);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$empty_anchors = $xpath->evaluate('//a[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]');
$i = $empty_anchors->length - 1; 
while ($i > -1) { 
    $element = $empty_anchors->item($i);  
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element); 
    $i--; 
} 

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `firstChild` exists, just change your `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach($as as $a)
{
    if($a->firstChild === NULL && is_object($a))
    {
        #remove links without nodevalues
        $a->parentNode->removeChild($a);
    }
}
```

> firstChild
>
> The first child of this node. If there is no such node, this returns NULL